# {Core Java with Spring} calling PL SQL stored procedure via plain JDBC - who should ideally do transaction management

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, transactions

My application calls the Oracle Stored Procedure from Java/Spring. There is no Hibernate or iBatis or Spring JDBC templates.
This server side/middle tier is 'thin' in the sense there is no business logic checks, no validations; It just acts a data transfer
layer between the UI and the database. The java code calls the stored procedure in case of data retrieval or data persistence.
The Stored Procedure is the big guy who  interacts with the various table/table-relationships and aggregates the data.

Question - **In this case, who should ideally manage the transaction? From the Java code or from the Stored-procedure?**

Usually when the middle tier manages the data or does business logic, or does the validation we would either use plain JDBC/ORM frameworks to 
interact with the various tables and hence manages the transaction as well. 
But in my use-case, the SP is interacting with the tables, takes the decision whether the data is properly retrieved or able to persist,
why should it rely on middle-tier to manage the transaction alone. It can very well know whether to commit a transaction or rollback it.

Isn't it better to always write a SP that act a high level interface for the aggregation function in case of a data retrieval,
or a summarize function in case of data persistence, and finally do a transaction commit or transaction rollback?

The middle tier needs to handle the transaction management only if it is expected to call more than one SP 
for a particular operation. As long as the java code calls ONLY a SINGLE stored procedure for a particular operation[fetch/update/delete],
isn't it good to manage the transaction commit and rollback in the Stored procedure itself?

In case something went wrong inside the SP, it can rollback the transaction and raise an exception, and Java 
would then pass that exception message [or log it and pass a custom exception] to the UI.

A counter thought is let the SP's raise an exception in case of any exception encountered, and the Java code in-turn catch the exception and do a transaction rollback.
If there is no exception in calling the SP, let it do a transaction commit.
But then here, the SP already whether the transaction is a success or failure, then why we can't do a commit or rollback then itself, and instead
pass that information in the form of a exception or no-exception and let java code do the commit/rollback?

update: One thing that justifies the need of Java code to manage the transaction is when it calls MULTIPLE SP's for a SINGLE operation.
But then, the same result can be achieved by a high level routine that does the logic of internally calling the individual routines, and finally
take teh decision of commit/rollback.

Please share your thoughts/recommendations/design suggestions on this.

PS: I haven't share any code here, but this a programmatic design question, as to who should manage the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a philosophic question.
There is no better here it’s a matter of your preference and your area of specialty.

DBA’s will love store procedures approach java programmers won’t.

Regarding transaction management I will prefer a unified approach rater then a hybrid solution.
Transaction management is complex and I would prefer sticking to one approach if you use SP use the database transaction management. If you chose to use jdbc or ORM use the jdbc transaction management or spring abstraction for jdbc trx management.

SP approach has its pros and cons:

**Pro:**

1. You can tailor database specific queries and a may gain superior
   performance
2. Less third party dependencies that will result with
   lighter distribution
3. You are a DBA

**Cons:**

1. You are database depended
2. Your JUnit’s will require interacting with a database
3. You need a DBA

Anyway I would use spring JDBC Template which, from my point of view, is a good JDBC abstraction that save you boilerplate code and bugs.

If you go for java transaction management I will add Spring PlatformTransactionManager.

Adding spring-jdbc and spring-tx jar will not have a huge size effect. 
The two jars are around 800k I guess some additional depended jar will be added as well .

Comment: Thank you, but before diving in, a clarification - you mentioned "Your approach has its prons and cons". Infact I didn't decide on any approach. As of now I don't have any. Can you clarify what you assumed as my approach was, so that I can better understand your post. I think you assumed me suggesting for transaction management from Stored procedure

Comment: my specific question is regarding transaction management, and not regarding usage of stored procedures vs SpringJDBC/Hibernate. Just want to ensure if you understood correctly